# Sound Issues With Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

I am writing a front end to a game engine in Javascript. The engine runs on the server and sends pictures and sounds to the web browser through 'SignalR'. I am using the React framework.

As the game runs the server sends small sound samples in WAVE format, passed into this component through the AudioPlayerProps.

I am having two main issues with the sound. The first is that the sound sounds 'disjointed'.
And the second is that after a time the sound just stops playing. I can see sound being queued in the audio queue, but the 'playNextAudioTrack' method is not being called. There are no errors in the console to explain this.

If this is not the best way to provide sound for a game front end, please let me know.

Also if you want to see any more code please let me know. This is a huge multi tiered project so I am only showing what I think you need to see.

Right now I am testing in Chrome. At this stage I need to turn on the DEV tools to get past the 'user didn't interact with page so you can't play any sound issue'. I will sort that issue out in due course.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export interface AudioPlayerProps {
    data: string;
}
export const AudioPlayer = function (props: AudioPlayerProps): JSX.Element {
    const [audioQueue, setAudioQueue] = useState<string[]>([])

    useEffect(
        () => {
            if (props.data != undefined) {
                audioQueue.push(props.data);
            }
        }, [props.data]);

    const playNextAudioTrack = () => {
        if (audioQueue.length > 0) {
            const audioBase64 = audioQueue.pop();

            const newAudio = new Audio(`data:audio/wav;base64,${audioBase64}`)
            newAudio.play().then(playNextAudioTrack).catch(
                (error) => {
                    setTimeout(playNextAudioTrack, 10);
                }
            )

        }
        else {
            setTimeout(playNextAudioTrack, 10);
        }
    }

    useEffect(playNextAudioTrack, []);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Try using the canplay and ended hooks to playback and clean up the audio tags.  I don't have any actual experience, so I don't know what effect it has on such realtime sensitive sound playing, but I can't imagine it would work well with React state batching and SignalR socket data interaction.    I've had experience porting Web Audio API and sound playback apps on multiple platform browsers: there's a few buggy platforms where the playback is resolved by putting the playback in setTimeout calls.  I think, though, putting them in the error handler caused problems. I used Web Audio fallbacks

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. Here is the typescript class I wrote to handle chunked audio in JavaScript.

I am not a JavaScript expert and therefore there may be faults.

EDIT: After running it in 15 minute lots several times, it failed a couple of times at about the 10 minute mark. Still needs some work.

```
// mostly from https://gist.github.com/revolunet/e620e2c532b7144c62768a36b8b96da2
// Modified to play chunked audio for games
import { setInterval } from "timers";

// 
const MaxScheduled = 10;
const MaxQueueLength = 2000;
const MinScheduledToStopDraining = 5;
export class WebAudioStreamer {

    constructor() {
        this.isDraining = false;
        this.isWorking = false;
        this.audioStack = [];
        this.nextTime = 0;
        this.numberScheduled = 0;

        setInterval(() => {
            if (this.audioStack.length && !this.isWorking) {
                this.scheduleBuffers(this);
            }
        }, 0);
    }

    context: AudioContext;
    audioStack: AudioBuffer[];
    nextTime: number;
    numberScheduled: number;
    isDraining: boolean;
    isWorking: boolean;

    pushOntoAudioStack(encodedBytes: number[]) {
        if (this.context == undefined) {
            this.context = new (window.AudioContext)();
        }

        const encodedBuffer = new Uint8ClampedArray(encodedBytes).buffer;
        const streamer: WebAudioStreamer = this;

        if (this.audioStack.length > MaxQueueLength) {
            this.audioStack = [];
        }

        streamer.context.decodeAudioData(encodedBuffer, function (decodedBuffer) {
            streamer.audioStack.push(decodedBuffer);
        }
        );
    }

    scheduleBuffers(streamer: WebAudioStreamer) {
        streamer.isWorking = true;

        if (streamer.context == undefined) {
            streamer.context = new (window.AudioContext)();
        }

        if (streamer.isDraining && streamer.numberScheduled <= MinScheduledToStopDraining) {
            streamer.isDraining = false;
        }

        while (streamer.audioStack.length && !streamer.isDraining) {
            var buffer = streamer.audioStack.shift();
            var source = streamer.context.createBufferSource();
            source.buffer = buffer;
            source.connect(streamer.context.destination);
            if (streamer.nextTime == 0)
                streamer.nextTime = streamer.context.currentTime + 0.01;  /// add 50ms latency to work well across systems - tune this if you like
            source.start(streamer.nextTime);

            streamer.nextTime += source.buffer.duration; // Make the next buffer wait the length of the last buffer before being played
            streamer.numberScheduled++;

            source.onended = function () {
                streamer.numberScheduled--;
            }

            if (streamer.numberScheduled == MaxScheduled) {
                streamer.isDraining = true;
            }

        };

        streamer.isWorking = false;
    }
}
```